# Reading a postgres timestamp with timezone field returns GMT +1

Tags: c#, postgresql-9.5, timestamp-with-timezone

On a client's postgres 9.5 db, there are fields with "timestamp with time zone" with a value of eg "2019-07-31 15:20:31+00"

[image: postgres field]

But from C#, when I read that value using a simple SELECT query

```
SELECT mp_purchase_date FROM auk_order WHERE id = 12345 LIMIT 1...
```

the value returned is:

> "2019-07-31 16:20:31+00"

But if I change mp_purchase_date to "timestamp without time zone", then it's fine.

I have checked that 
    postgresql.config has GMT ticked.
    SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now())/3600.0 returns 0.
    SHOW timezone outputs GMT

Note that updating the field is fine and sets the value to whatever is passed in.

It's almost as if Postgres is on GMT +1.

My client's postgres version is:

[image: Client's postgres version]

What am i missing?

Comment: `"2019-07-31 16:20:31+00"` and the value you showed are the same point in time, just viewed from different timezones. They have the same underlying value. The only thing that is different is how they are represented as strings. Functions like ToString() retrieve the culture information and timezone from the OS.

Comment: Trying to deal with timezones will lead to primarily one thing - Madness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY I have 3 basic rules regarding DateTimes: 1) Always store, transmit and retreive the UTC value. 2) Avoid storing, retreiving or transmitting the value as string 3) If yo ucan not avoid string, pick the same culture and encoding on all endpoints. You do not want to add those to your worries. | However in some cases option 1 is not an option. In this case, you are hosed and have to deal with timezones yourself.

Comment: @Christopher, When I write the data back to the db, it writes "2019-07-31 16:20:31+00" which when read back becomes "...17:20:31+00".  Funny thing is, this only happens on my client's machine and not on my mine.  Both W10, and time zones etc are set to GMT.   I can't change anything re your rules and am forced to use have I've inherited (to a point).  Though I will take a closer look at ToString() so +1 for that pointer.   Sai.

Comment: I can only repeat that the 3 rules are a good idea. You really do not want to deal with DateTimes.